# write text file into csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, file, reader, writer

I'm trying to write a text file into csv file using csv package in python using this code:

```
import csv

with open(r'C:\Users\soso-\Desktop\SVM\DataSet\drug_list.txt') as f:
    with open('integrated_x.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer= csv.writer(out_file)
        for line in f:
            print(line.strip())
            writer.writerow(line.strip())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwGrf.png)

I expected the the file to be as in terminal, but I dont know why it written in the csv file like this

how can I fix it
the data appears in csv like this :

```
D,B,0,0,6,3,2

D,B,0,0,4,3,3

D,B,0,1,1,9,4

D,B,0,0,2,7,3

D,B,0,2,5,3,0
```

I want the csv file to be like this :

```
DB00632,
DB00433,
DB01194,
DB00273,
DB02530,
```

Comment: Please reformat your code. Upon initial inspection it looks like you have some erroneously placed colons, for starters.

Comment: Is input file simply a drug id (e.g. "DB00632", etc.) each on a seperate line?

Comment: @CodeMonkey yes, this is exactly how the text looks

Comment: Add space as delimiter in writer= csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=' ')

it is not empty string but string with single space  -> ' '     not like ''

Comment: To just output the drug name with "," don't need a csvwriter. Can just write the drugname with a ",", e.g. `fout.write(f"{line.strip()},\n")`

Comment: I tried this but it appears like this D B 0 2 5 3 0
@MuhammadZeeshan

Comment: @SaraAlmashharawi try without spacce? like -> ''

Comment: Your input file is a perfectly valid CSV file already - there is no need for comma separators when there isn't more than one thing on each line to need separating.  Why are you trying to convert it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected error you are seeing with output like "D,B,0,0,6,3,2" is due to `writer.writerow()` expecting a list or iterable argument. The string DB00632 is then iterated into characters and CSV output has each letter separated by a comma without using a CSV writer.

If just want to append a comma (,) to end of each drug id then can just output the drug name followed by a comma and a new line.

Note the CSV file doesn't yet have a header line and there is nothing in the second column.

```python
with open('drug_list.txt') as f:
    with open('integrated_x.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            print(line)
            out_file.write(f"{line},\n")
```

If input looks like a drug id on each line (e.g. DB00632) then the output would be as expected:

```
DB00632,
DB00433,
DB01194,
DB00273,
DB02530,
```